# Azure Website "Always On"

Tags: azure, cakephp-3.0, azure-web-app-service

I've a CakePHP Website hosted on Azure Website (Standard). When I switched "Always On" on. It seems to keep giving me a 403 error after logged in my WebApp. When I turned off and the error goes away. How can I turn on "Always On" and resolve the 403 error? . This error pop out after I logged in my Webapp. Do I need to put any additional code to web.config to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It's seems unlikely that Always On would cause this. The only things Always On does is send a ping request to the root of your app every couple minutes (with an AlwaysOn user agent). It's really not much different from sending similar requests yourself at the same interval.

If you enable http logging, you should see those requests.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for getting back. Will the Always On affects the session? It seems like after I logged in it will timeout quickly and I will logout automatically.

Comment: It should not. It does absolutely nothing other than what I described, which is to ping the root of your site every couple minutes.